# Change :root variables on different pages with a class

Tags: html, css, postcss, cssnext

Is it possible to use the `:root` selector with an ID or Class? I'm trying to flip colors on a different page.

```
:root {
  --color-one: red;
  --color-two: blue;
}

/* Can something like this happen? */
.posts:root {
  --color-one: green;
  --color-two: yellow;
}
```

I want to overwrite the root variables when a class is introduced. I know I could achieve with JS but I want to use pure CSS if possible.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax may be a little different from what you have here but sure you can, that's the power of CSS!

You can override the css variables in any class. You don't need :root for the overrides, and if your overridden values should affect the whole page, add that class to the body tag.

```css
:root {
  --color-one: red;
  --color-two: blue;
}

/* Overrides settings in :root */
.posts {
  --color-one: green;
  --color-two: yellow;
}



p {
  color: var(--color-one);
  background-color: var(--color-two);
}
```

```html
<p>
Test
</p>
<p>
Test
</p>

<div class="posts">
<!-- just add this class to the body tag on your other page -->
<p>
Test
</p><p>
Test
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

The syntax would be :

```
:root.post {
    /* cSS declarations */
}
```

You could have the same stylesheet on 2 pages then apply the `posts` class to the HTML element.

```
:root {
  --color-one: yellow;
  --color-two: green;
  background-color: var(--color-one);
  color: var(--color-two);
}

:root.posts {
  --color-one: green;
  --color-two: yellow;
  background-color: var(--color-one);
  color: var(--color-two);
}
```

#### Page 1: green text on yellow background

*Updated with child descendant*

```css
:root {
  --color-one: yellow;
  --color-two: green;
  background-color: var(--color-one);
  color: var(--color-two);
}

:root.posts {
  --color-one: green;
  --color-two: yellow;
  background-color: var(--color-one);
  color: var(--color-two);
}

.special {
  color: #f0f;
  font-style: italic;
}

:root.posts .special {
  color: #f90;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      ghjkghjkg
    </p>
    <p class="special">Special content</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Page 2: yellow text on green background

*Updated with child descendant*

```css
:root {
  --color-one: yellow;
  --color-two: green;
  background-color: var(--color-one);
  color: var(--color-two);
}

:root.posts {
  --color-one: green;
  --color-two: yellow;
  background-color: var(--color-one);
  color: var(--color-two);
}

.special {
  color: #f0f;
  font-style: italic;
}

:root.posts .special {
  color: #f90;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<html class="posts">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      ghjkghjkg
    </p>
    <p class="special">Special content</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however i cant seem to get this to work. Im setting `:root.posts` variables after the `:root` and when the posts class is introduced nothing happens. Maybe a postcss setting?