# Create new color scheme for dark-light mode in bootstrap sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5, scss-mixins

I want to create dark mode for a web site which use bootstrap. I have to add new root class which includes all boostrap colors. Here is my colors.scss:

```
$primary:#065FC6;
$secondary:#263C5C;
$success:#49C96D;
$danger:#FD7972;
$warning:#FF965D;
$light:#F8F8F8;
$body-color: #263C5C;

$custom-colors: (
  "brd-default": $body-color
  );
```

I want create new class like this:

```
:root.dark{
    // override colors and classes for dark mode
    $primary:#012345;
    $secondary:#111111;
    $success:#222222;
}
```

So how can i copy and paste all bootstrap colors for new color scheme?

If i can add colors, i will change HTML class so my root(color scheme) will be:

[image]

in my styles.scss:

```
@import "./colors";// custom colors
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

Comment: @Zim i changed question. Would you look at please?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067695/change-root-variables-on-different-pages-with-a-class), there's no way to attach a class to `:root`. However, you don't need this to achieve what you want.

Simply make a `dark` class then you can add that as desired to the html or body tag.

Make all the needed theme color changes *inside* .dark{}, and then @import "bootstrap". When `.dark` doesn't exist on the body, the theme colors will return to Bootstrap defaults.

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";


.dark {

    /* redefine theme colors for dark theme */
    $primary: #012345;
    $secondary: #111111;
    $success: #222222;
    $dark: #000;
    
    $theme-colors: (
        "primary": $primary,
        "secondary": $secondary,
        "success": $success,
        "danger": $danger,
        "info": $indigo,
        "dark": $dark,
        "light": $light,
    );

    /* redefine theme color variables */
    @each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
        --#{$variable-prefix}#{$color}: #{$value};
    }

    /* redefine theme color rgb vars (used for bg- colors) */
    $theme-colors-rgb: map-loop($theme-colors, to-rgb, "$value");
    @each $color, $value in $theme-colors-rgb {
        --#{$variable-prefix}#{$color}-rgb: #{$value};
    }

    $body-color: #eeeeee;
    $body-bg: #263C5C;
    
    --#{$variable-prefix}body-color: #{$body-color};
    --#{$variable-prefix}body-bg: #{$body-bg};
      
    @import "bootstrap";
}
```

[Bootstrap 5 Dark Theme](https://codeply.com/p/DBGWVMiKcE#)

Comment: thanks, but i can't override ".bg-light" class.

Comment: I am unable to override this. I couldn't.

Comment: I updated the answer.. you need to reset `$theme-colors-rgb` with the new theme colors too

Comment: The https://github.com/vinorodrigues/bootstrap-dark-5 proof of concept project shows how to achieve dark mode with Bootstrap using 6 different variants.

The `bootstrap-nightshade` variation show how to achieve dark mode with a `.dark` class set.

Comment: Thanks @vino -- I'm aware of your dark mode stuff.  you should post an answer OR a comment to the question.

Comment: @Zim i am getting this error: "Syntax Error: SassError: ("primary": #012345, "secondary": #111111, "success": #222222, "dark": #000) isn't a valid CSS value."

Comment: is this plain css or scss?

Comment: This works for me only if I put `@import "bootstrap";` at the very end, outside of `.dark{}`

Comment: i dont understand why `@import "bootstrap"`` is inside the `. dark` class. Doesnt this contain the complete bootstrap css tree?