# The most appropriate way to implement dark/light/... mode in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, bootstrap-5

How to properly Introduce themes like dark and light themes In Bootstrap 5.  Should it be done by css/scss or js or with both of them.
Should we overwrite classes with a css file like dark.css?
Should we switch classes like bg-dark, bg-light etc with js?
I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667437/create-new-color-scheme-for-dark-light-mode-in-bootstrap-sass/68670276#68670276), but I think there is a way that meet all needs.
The other question is if we want more than two themes other than dark/white what should we do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing dark mode for bootstrap is a long task as there are multiple variables that need to be changed.The simplier aproach will be using var() with .dark/.light in root, but still there are functions of bootstrap that needs a color to function properly.